# Direct upload to Goolge Cloud Storage bucket from website

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My company's website is managed and hosted by a third party.
We'd like to provide a portal on the website that allows our clients to upload files directly to a Google Cloud Storage bucket without the file going through the website (these uploads can span thousands of files and several GB).

I've found a good guide for how to do it on AWS (https://softwareontheroad.com/aws-s3-secure-direct-upload/) but can't even determine if the equivalent functionality exists for Google, let alone how to do it.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: the Cloud Run +Cloud Storage could meet your requirement with a low cost. There is a [solution](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-simple-web-upload-interface-with-google-cloud-run-and-cloud-storage-eba0a97edc7b) provided by the third party with full explanation and code for you to refer

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Thats a great help. Need to figure out authentication for the website into Google Cloud, but great to see a worked example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider providing us some more technical details on what you want to achieve. Things like programming languages, server platform, cloud provider where the website is hosted…

In a generalistic way, I can tell you that Google Cloud Storage has a similar approach to upload files which is [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

For example, if you are coding in Python with this you can upload a file to a bucket using a signed URL:

```
import datetime

from google.cloud import storage


def generate_upload_signed_url_v4(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Generates a v4 signed URL for uploading a blob using HTTP PUT.

    # bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
# blob_name = 'your-object-name'

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

url = blob.generate_signed_url(
    version="v4",
    # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
    expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
    # Allow PUT requests using this URL.
    method="PUT",
    content_type="application/octet-stream",
)

print("Generated PUT signed URL:")
print(url)
print("You can use this URL with any user agent, for example:")
print(
    "curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' "
    "--upload-file my-file '{}'".format(url)
)
return url
```

Then you can implement this as needed by your organization

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for the response. Signed URLs seem to be the way to go, now just need to liase with the website people about how to get their server authenticated so it can generate the signed URLs.